# How can I check if character belongs to a group of symbols in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

The task is to count all the punctuation signs in a string. How can I check if character belongs to this group ".,!?;:". I'm doing it this way

```
signs' curSgn ('.':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
signs' curSgn (',':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
signs' curSgn ('?':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
signs' curSgn ('!':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
signs' curSgn (':':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
signs' curSgn (';':list) = (signs' (curSgn + 1) list)
```

But is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Comment: `punc :: String -> Int` implemented for example as `punc = length . filter (\`elem\` ".,?!:;")`

Comment: @jd823592 You should post your comment as an answer so that you can get accepted and upvoted and help others find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the symbols you are interested in with `filter` and count the number of occurrences using `length`. Filter takes a list of values and returns a maximum sublist containing values that satisfy some property (e.g. being a punctuation mark).

```
punctuation :: String -> Int
punctuation s = length (filter (...) s)
```

what is the `...`? It needs to tell if a character is a punctuation or not, i.e. a predicate of type `Char -> Bool`. How to tell if a character is in a given list?

```
isPunctuation :: Char -> Bool
isPunctuation c = c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';']
```

putting these together

```
punctuation :: String -> Int
punctuation = length . filter (`elem` ".,?!:;")
```

notice that a list of characters `['.', ...]` is in fact a string and you can write it as `".,?!:;"` in short. Also notice the pointfree notation, instead of defining `punctuation` in terms of what it does to its only argument `s`, we say that the function `punctuation` is equal to a composition of functions `length` and `filter ...`. Also notice the [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) notation for binding the second argument of `elem` rather than the first. There is also [`isPunctuation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html).